# Similar object transform java

Tags: java

I have a java class that models an object, another that models the same object with few differences. How I can transform the second object in the first?
thanks

Comment: Please provide your code so we can review it

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Please post your code.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are trying to imply, do you mean you have two objects with some differences (of same type) and you want to make second one like first one ?

Comment: I have a class that models an object then i have another that is the copy of the former one with other attributes

Comment: Sorry if the question was unanderstandable, but i solved doing a function that takes the second object as a parameter and in output the first one, copying the attributes I need

Answer (score 1):

[Apache's BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) class has a [copyProperties](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) static method that will copy all similarly-named properties between from a source Object to a destination Object.